# Compare two lists, then add missing data to the bottom of one list?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have been searching and searching and I've tried a dozen different things, and the array formula that added 50,000 rows to my sheet (I didn't even know that was possible...) and crashed my browser was the final straw. So I'm asking for help...

Basically, I have a static list of names in sheet1(Grades) that are sorted alphabetically. I have an importrange in sheet2(Data) with another list of names, *not* sorted alphabetically (And it cannot be sorted alphabetically.) Something like this:

```
Grades:

Bill
Charlie
Fred
George
Percy
Ron
```

and
    Data:

```
Ron
Bill
Fred
Percy
Harry
Hermione
Molly
Arthur
```

What I need is to imput a formula in the cell below the last name on sheet1(Grades) that checks all of the names above that cell, compares them to the names on sheet2(Data), and returns the first name that's missing. For example:

```
Grades:

Bill
Charlie
Fred
George
Percy
Ron
(Formula Here) = Harry
(Formula Here) = Hermione
Etc.
```

The New names should always be at the bottom of the Data list, if that help any.

[Here's a link to a copy of the spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Co5deFPmZlC-DnqSMz2ylyL3T78qPfw7AmFuYviMBj4/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope I got the permissions correct... Most of it was protected, but I think it should be open for edits now. Any help would be *much* appreciated. I really didn't think I was trying to do something that difficult, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I take it you want basically the difference between two lists. I've put this formula in the cell below the last entry in column B in Grades, hope this is what you want:

```
=filter(Data!A1:A40, iserror(match(Data!A1:A40, B5:B45, 0)))
```

Comment: Filters. Ugh, I feel like an idiot, lol. Thank you!! I can't believe how long I messed with this last night only to wake up to a solution this simple! But, yes, that does exactly what I want it to!